# CALayer invalid geometry , Mfmailcomposer

Tags: iphone, calayer, nan, mfmailcomposer

Am trying to open `MFMailComposer` class, but it crashes on `init` method giving `CALayer` position contains NaN: [nan 24.5]

Am trying to present `MFmailcomposer` on a `ViewController`

```
VSMailPicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];  
VSMailPicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:VSMailPicker animated:YES];
```

Don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`MFMailComposeViewController` uses some native elements that shouldn't be categorized. So, you have to be sure there aren't any categories on elements like `UITextField` or `UITextView`.